# Order by date and other column

Tags: r, sorting, date, dataframe

I am trying to sort my data frame after two columns. The first column is the number either **0** or **6317** and the second column is the **date in mm-yy** format from January to December from different years.
Below is just a selection of my dataframe:

```
         number    date         count
    1     0         Sep-13       10
    2     0         Jan-12       15
    3     0         Feb-13       4
    4     0         Oct-12       13
    5     0         Nov-13       14
    6    6317       Jan-12       20
    7    6317       Nov-13       40
    8    6317       Dez-13       20
    9    6317       Feb-13       10
   10    6317       Oct-12       15
   11    6317       Oct-13       19
```

I have used the following commands

```
orderbydate <- count[order(as.Date(count$date, format=c("%b-%y")),]
```

and

```
orderbydate <- count[order(count[,1], count[,2]),]
```

I was planning on having it look something like this in the end.

```
date        6317      0

Jan-12      20        15
Feb-12      8         10
Mrch-12     15        20
.           .          .
.           .          .
.           .          .
Jan-13      18        19
Feb-13      10        4
Mrch-13     14        2
Apr-13      11        9
```

Answer (score 2):

We can convert to `yearmon` class with `zoo` and then `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
count %>%
      arrange(number, as.yearmon(date, '%b-%y'))
```

---

Or without using packages, convert the 'date' to `Date` class by `paste`ing a day (for e.g. 01) and then do the `order`

```
count[order(count$number, as.Date(paste0(count$date, "-01"), "%b-%y-%d")),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cast()` function from the reshape library.

The below code will yield the desired result:
`library(reshape)
 new_df <- cast(count, date~number)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option without using any packages:

DATA:

```
number  date    count
0   Sep-13  10
0   Jan-12  15
0   Feb-13  4
0   Oct-12  13
0   Nov-13  14
6317    Jan-12  20
6317    Nov-13  40
6317    Dec-13  20
6317    Feb-13  10
6317    Oct-12  15
6317    Oct-13  19
```

CODE:

```
dt <- read.table('clipboard', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
dt$date <- as.Date(paste(dt$date, '01', sep = '-'), format = '%b-%y-%d')


> dt
   number       date count
1       0 2013-09-01    10
2       0 2012-01-01    15
3       0 2013-02-01     4
4       0 2012-10-01    13
5       0 2013-11-01    14
6    6317 2012-01-01    20
7    6317 2013-11-01    40
8    6317 2013-12-01    20
9    6317 2013-02-01    10
10   6317 2012-10-01    15
11   6317 2013-10-01    19
```

To get what you indicated above, we can use `merge`:

```
> merge(dt[dt$number == 6317, 2:3], dt[dt$number == 0, 2:3], by = 'date', suffixes = c('_6317', '_0'), fill = T, all = T)
        date count_6317 count_0
1 2012-01-01         20      15
2 2012-10-01         15      13
3 2013-02-01         10       4
4 2013-09-01         NA      10
5 2013-10-01         19      NA
6 2013-11-01         40      14
7 2013-12-01         20      NA
```

Comment: `clipboard` in `read.table` allows it to read data that is copied to the clipboard (ctrl + c) on the webpage. It is pretty much the same as `readClipboard`. This is why it is recommended to share sample data for your question using `dput`. Hope this helps :)